# Lever switch identification

Tags: switches, identification

I have this lever actuated, panel mount, momentary action microswitch with two series of contacts: each set of contacts operates in the (ON)-OFF-(ON) configuration.
Judging by the looks of it, i assume this to be quite old. 
I can gauge that "6A125V.AC" from one of the pictures is the contact rating for voltage and current; in the same picture the switch action is also described, the markings ON OFF ON are clearly visible.

So far any attempt at googling the other two strings "8829 japan" or "BB2041 MICRO" along with some related keyword like switch/microswitch/rocker/lever/temporary etc. did not yield any useful result; has anyone see this and if so, is a datasheet available online?

[image: pic 1]
[image: pic 2]
[image: pic 3]

Comment: It was probably made the 29th week of 1988 so, good luck in finding a data sheet. There will be many modern functional alternatives of course.

Comment: That looks like a **toggle** switch, perhaps that term will assist you in searching.

Comment: @Andyaka  how were you able to guess that 8829 is the manufacturng date? it's fairly obvious after you pointed out, but i couldn't notice it myself 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the first picture, I interpreted the model number as `8B2041`. I searched for `8B2041 Micro Switch` and found [this link at Digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/3tjwfw21), and [this datasheet](https://www.nidec-copal-electronics.com/e/catalog/switch/8b.pdf) from Nidec Copal Electronics. Unsurprisingly, it is no longer manufactured.

[image: Product model table from datasheet]

The above table seems to confirm that this model number coincides with the configuration of the switch you have.